# Return multiple times in PHP

Tags: php

So I am trying to return multiple values in a foreach loop.
The code looks like this:

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE username=%s", $user['username']);
foreach ($result as $results) {
  return response()->json(["success" => true, "list" => [["name" => $results['name'], "key" => $results['key'], "expire" => $results['expire']]]]);
}
```

I am using Meekrodb just so you know.
So I basically have a database with x amount of rows. Each row has a different username depending on the username of the person who registered. So it checks for the usernames to match. And it works fine with the first row, but if I have more than one row it doesn't want to return the second row, only the first one.

So yeah instead of the code returning: 
`{"success":true,"list" [{"name":"whatever","key":"123","expire":"Never"}]}`

Despite multiple rows with the same username.


 It should return something like this:

```
{"success":true,"list" [{"name":"whatever","key":"123","expire":"Never"}]}
{"success":true,"list" [{"name":"whatever2","key":"456","expire":"Tomorrow"}]}
```

It might seem a bit confusing, but all I really want is to return multiple values or something in that direction.

Comment: Build an array and return that

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build and return the array like below

```
    $result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE username=%s", $user['username']);
    foreach ($result as $results) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $results) {
        $data["success"] = true;
        $data["list"]['name'] = $results['name'];
        $data["list"]['key'] = $results['key'];
        $data["list"]['key'] = $results['key']
        $data["list"]['expire'] = $results['expire']
        //return response()->json(["success" => true, "list" => [["name" => $results['name'], "key" => $results['key'], "" => $results['expire']]]]);
    }
    return echo json_encode($data);
```